# D3.js Timeline does not filter Points of interest on map at all

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filtering

I have combined two visualizations of different data. 
The first one is showing a streamgraph on asylum data of germany over the past 12 months.
[image: 12months]
The second one is spawning points on a map. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491737/d3-slider-and-dates-filtered-on-a-timeline) is actually running now but now it is broken because i combined both in one html file.
[image: map]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/d3.slider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/temp.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/d3.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/socket.io-0.9.10.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/caress-0.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    $(function() {
        window.client = new Caress.Client({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 5000
        });
        client.connect();
    });
  </script>
<div id="slider3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/streamgraph.js"></script> -->

<div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton"
           type="button"
           value="Show Data for second Attemp"
           onclick="updateSecond('data/folgeantraege_monatlich_2015_mitentscheidungenbisnovember.csv')" /></div>
<div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton"
           type="button"
           value="Show Data for first Attemp"
           onclick="updateFirst('data/erstantraege_monatlich_2015_mitentscheidungenbisnovember.csv')" /></div>
<div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton"
           type="button"
           value="Show both"
           onclick="updateBoth('data/erstantraege_monatlich_2015_mitentscheidungenbisnovember.csv', 'data/folgeantraege_monatlich_2015_mitentscheidungenbisnovember.csv')" /></div>


<div class="chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/streamgraph.js"></script>




<script>

</script>

</body>
```

Don't mind the socket.io and the caress-server part. (I'm also working on multitouch but thats not essential for the moment)
The js files are on my [repo](https://github.com/RitterLean/Timeline_world)

I also changed the d.date in my streamgraph js so it does not interfere with the date of my map

```
var graph = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  d3.csv(csvpath, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.graphDate = dateParser(d.Datum);
      d.value = +d.Summe;
  });
```

It's broken because I think something is wrong with the reading of the data because it is always projecting the whole year at once in the map part but I can't figure out what's causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your slider callback function like this:

```
dp = d3.time.format("%d.%m.%Y").parse;//NOTE: the change in variable name here
var minDate = dp("01.01.2015");
var maxDate = dp("31.12.2015");
var secondsInDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
d3.select('#slider3').call(d3.slider()
  .axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate)
  .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
    newData = site_data.features.filter(function(d){
      return dp(d.properties.date) < new Date(value);
    });
    console.log(newData);
        console.log("New set size ", newData.length);

    displaySites(newData)
  })
);
```

The reason is that inside steamGraph.js you have written 
dateParser as `dateParser = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;`

And inside the slider you were using the same global variable `dateParser`, thus i have changed the name of the variable as `dp = d3.time.format("%d.%m.%Y").parse;`

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FNnsIrkhRdCitdtjKRPP?p=preview)

Hope this helps!